# FCM cloud function for server less push notification android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I requires an example for firebase cloud function for server less push notification for android.

Answer (score 2):

Enter this code on the Android Side, where you would want to trigger the cloud function to send the notification, for Eg. in a chat application when you send a message:

```
Message message =
            new Message(timestamp, -timestamp, dayTimestamp, body, ownerUid, userUid);
    mDatabase
            .child("notifications")
            .child("messages")
            .push()
            .setValue(message);
    mDatabase
            .child("messages")
            .child(userUid)
            .child(ownerUid)
            .push()
            .setValue(message);
    if (!userUid.equals(ownerUid)) {
        mDatabase
                .child("messages")
                .child(ownerUid)
                .child(userUid)
                .push()
                .setValue(message);
    }
```

And this code in the directory where you initialize your Firebase Cloud Functions which gets triggered on sending of the message in your Android app:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/messages/{pushId}')
.onWrite(event => {
    const message = event.data.current.val();
    const senderUid = message.from;
    const receiverUid = message.to;
    const promises = [];

    if (senderUid == receiverUid) {
        //if sender is receiver, don't send notification
        promises.push(event.data.current.ref.remove());
        return Promise.all(promises);
    }

    const getInstanceIdPromise = admin.database().ref(`/users/${receiverUid}/instanceId`).once('value');
    const getReceiverUidPromise = admin.auth().getUser(receiverUid);

    return Promise.all([getInstanceIdPromise, getReceiverUidPromise]).then(results => {
        const instanceId = results[0].val();
        const receiver = results[1];
        console.log('notifying ' + receiverUid + ' about ' + message.body + ' from ' + senderUid);

        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: receiver.displayName,
                body: message.body,
                icon: receiver.photoURL
            }
        };

        admin.messaging().sendToDevice(instanceId, payload)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Error sending message:", error);
            });
    });
});
```

For more information check this - [Serverless notifications with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://android.jlelse.eu/serverless-notifications-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase-685d7c327cd4)

Comment: Thanks ! but i checked it already, it does not sends any notification, simply puts the message into the chat window.

Comment: @kanwal kaur, Have you tried entering the server code that is given on it's Github page, this [function](https://github.com/MahmoudAlyuDeen/FirebaseIM/blob/master/server/functions/index.js) is triggered when there is a new child node added (i.e your message) and a notification is sent to the device.

Comment: That code combined with [this tutorial](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html) should get you a long way.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16486184)

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih, sure! Thanks, will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @hsm59 Thank you, this helps keep answers valid and informative.

Comment: Thanks to all for spending your precious time, and as i think is was my first question, i am sorry for any kind of disrespect and lack in adequate questioning.. So i got my answer from below link..https://aaronczichon.de/2017/03/13/firebase-cloud-functions/

Comment: how we get the receiver uid ??????